# Change Spaces on all connected displays at once

Tags: macos, keyboard, spaces, mission-control

Just a simple question - my day-to-day setup is a MacBook Pro with 2 connected external displays. I want to try to organize my different "tasks" (writing code, testing/web browsing, and notes) into different Spaces. The keyboard shortcuts to change Spaces only take effect on my currently-selected screen.

Is there a way to change Spaces across all displays at once? If not with a built-in function, maybe a third-party app?

Comment: Are you using fullscreen apps? If not: Preferences -> Mission Control -> uncheck Separate Spaces.

Comment: Should be the answer @MateuszSzlosek There's no way round fullscreen apps (work of the devil;) so that's the way if not using fullscreen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a System preference for this, but then it makes fullscreen apps occupy only one screen at a time and the rest of the screens are black. To activate it:

**Preferences** -> **Mission Control** -> uncheck **Displays have separate Spaces**

reference: [Apple site](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202780)

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This seems to have done the trick. I use multiple spaces more than I use multiple fullscreen apps, so this is a trade-off I can make. :)